# Do I need a Semaphore when one process writes and the other one reads?

Tags: c#, serialization, ipc, semaphore

I have two processes named **A** and **B** (two exe-files: *A.exe* and *B.exe*) both implemented in C#.
Process **B** is called by process **A**.
In **A**, an object is serialized to a binary file by using the ISerializable interface. This happens every few milliseconds.
Process **B** deserializes this object (also every few milliseconds).

I am wondering whether I need a Semaphore when one process reads from a file, and the other writes. Is it possible that **B** tries to read the binary file, while **A** has not finished writing?

Comment: Yes, you need to synchronize access to files. But it's a very strange way of communication (file). Consider using WCF service - it will automatically pass serialized data from one process to other without need for synchronization. if there should be a delay between write and read, you can use MSMQ binding of WCF service which will store the request until it can be processed.

Comment: IMO Global [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) would be more suitable than Semaphore.

Comment: I agree that using a file for communication is a bit strange. You need to use a global semaphore/mutex/other synchronization for this. If you want to use file IO, maybe named pipes would be a better way, wouldn't need an actual file on disk?

Comment: As already mentioned, `Mutex` would be the right choice for IPC. You have to implement very simple Busy/Ready logic or go with several mutexes to make it more resistant and flexible.

Comment: Using a file to interop at millisecond rates is *not* a great idea.  At least use a named pipe or socket, you get the synchronization for free.

Comment: Thank you all!! I see that file I/O is not the best choice for IPC at millisecond rates. Can anyone point me to a tutorial that easily explaines the suggested methods (WCF service, Global Mutex, named pipe or socket)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the write is atomic meaning that that Process B can *only* see the new data after it's been completely written (and otherwise only sees the old data), then you don't need synchronization (semaphores etc.). This is usually the case when you have threads, and are writing a byte (writing a byte will be atomic) to memory which is to be shared.

In your case, you are serializing an entire object to a file which is definitely not atomic. In this case some synchronization between the two processes will be required.